# Nested {{#each}} isn't working

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating

I have the following arrays in my JavaScript:

```
let food = [
    'taco',
    'burrito',
    'hamburger',
  ]

let drinks = [
    'water',
    'milk',
    'soda',
  ]
```

I pass these to my Handlebars template and I do this:

```
{{#each food as |food|}}
  {{food}}
  {{#each drinks as |drink|}}
    {{drink}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But it only prints out

```
taco burrito hamburger
```

I would expect the output to be something like this (separated into newlines for legibility)

```
taco
water
milk
soda
burrito
water
milk
soda
hamburger
water
milk
soda
```

It appears to completely ignore the nested each loop. What is wrong here?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I added it. It's a loop within a loop. Is that not clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars nested 'each' syntax - not iterating over each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197731/handlebars-nested-each-syntax-not-iterating-over-each-element)

Comment: @JakeWilson no need for the attitude - you want help, be nice

Comment: No attitude intended. I sincerely wasn't sure if it was clear or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a context problem. The inner `each` is in the context of the outer one which doesn't have `drinks` defined.

Here is an example of a working template;

```
{{#each food as |food|}}
  {{food}}
  {{#each ../drinks as |drink|}}
    {{drink}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Here, we use `../` to backtrack to the parent context, where `drinks` is defined.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that `each` loops were scoped that way. Thank you!