# {{#each}} inside {{#each}} not working in handlebars with express

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a scenario where I want to use {{#each}} inside {{#each}}, I have two different arrays where I want to map one array with other with some if conditions.
for ex:

```
array1 = [{
key1:value1,
key2:value2,
key2:value2
}]

array2 = [{
arrar2key1:value1,
arrar2key2:value2,
arrar2key3:value2
}]
```

And now I want to iterate this each like

```
{{#each array1}}
  {{key1}}
       {{#each array2}}
             {{#if xyz "123"}}
                {{arrar2key}}
             {{/if}}
       {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I tried this but didn't worked for me. I am using this handlebar with my node express to create pdf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebars nested 'each' syntax - not iterating over each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197731/handlebars-nested-each-syntax-not-iterating-over-each-element)

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to do. You have two arrays, but each just contains a single object. I don't understand the purpose of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, is to iterate through `array2` of `array1`, in other words `array1.array2`. However, you don't want that to happen so you'll to change the code to the following to use the correct `array2` variable:

```html
{{#each array1}}
  {{key1}}
       {{#each ../array2}}
             {{#if xyz "123"}}
                {{arrar2key}}
             {{/if}}
       {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```